# Web Audio With Multiple Streams

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am attempting to stream audio via a RESTful based web service. My audio file contains two distinct AAC 228 Kbps stereo tracks. One is in English and the other Spanish.

My GET request returns the audio file no problem. However, it defaults to the first source on the file (in this case spanish).

Ultimately, I would like the end user to be able to use the browser and switch between the audio sources as needed. I already am aware that most browsers do not currently support the audioTracks API available through HTML5 and I would prefer not to limit my end users to IE or Edge.

This brings me to using the Web Audio API to try and manipulate the streams manually.

For testing my current HTML is just a play button.

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="audioActions()">Audio options</md-button>
```

My current .js is as follows:

```
var context;

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
function init() {
    try {
        // Fix up for prefixing
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
        context = new AudioContext();
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
    }
}

var onError = function() {
    $log.info("ERROR");
}

$scope.audioActions = function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://localhost...', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // Decode asynchronously
    request.onload = function() {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
            $log.info(buffer)

            var source = context.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = buffer;
            source.connect(context.destination);
            source.start(0);
        }, onError);
    }

    request.send();
};
```

This works for streaming the initial audio and works the same as if I were to use the `<audio>` tag.

Is there a way to be able to switch between the audio streams within the buffer?

Below is dump from ffmpeg -i on my file:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000000ea6920] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'E:\ServerFiles\tmp\audioExample.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 1982-08-11T07:52:37.000000Z
    title           : Test
    artist          : Audio Example
    album_artist    : Audio Example
    album           : Example
    genre           : Test
    track           : 1/20
    disc            : 1/1
    compilation     : 0
    gapless_playback: 0
    date            : 2017-08-16T08:00:00Z
    account_id      : 
    rating          : 0
    account_type    : 0
    season_number   : 0
    episode_sort    : 0
    media_type      : 1
    purchase_date   : 2017-08-16 15:59:27
    sort_album      : Audio Example
    composer        : Example
  Duration: 00:02:59.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you are asking at the moment is to use MediaSource Extensions.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource

Basically, you buffer the data, and then let the browser decode chunks.  When you want to switch to something else, just start feeding it chunks from the other stream to decode.

There is a better example here:  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/mse/basics

Comment: My problem right now is I don't know how to get those separate chunks. My service just returns one of many audio files. Embedded in these audio files are the two streams. By following the links I could understand how to buffer load the entire file. But nowhere in this documentation does it specify or give an example of having two audio streams in one file. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @cain4355 What's the container format for these files?  Can you provide the output of `ffmpeg -i yourfile`?

Comment: I added my ffmpeg results to my original post

Comment: @cain4355 Short of demuxing MP4 in JavaScript, I think what you have to do is split those into separate files.  I suspect that very soon (within a year), this will no longer be necessary (for modern browsers), as we'll get proper support for multiple audio tracks.  You can use something like `ffmpeg -i audioExample.m4a -map 0:0 -c:a copy audioExample-track-0.m4a` or similar to split those out.

Comment: How would I go about demuxing MP4 in JavaScript?

Comment: @cain4355 It's a nightmare.  :-)  Fortunately, it looks like you might not have to reinvent it yourself... I haven't used it, but check out the JavaScript build for mp4box:  https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js